# Find the matching between multiple tables in database

Tags: mysql, database, select, nested

I have four tables,in each one I have two columns   ID and Available. I need a Select Statement that finds the set of ID's that corresponds to available =0.

Table A: ID : 1 2 3 4 5 6

```
Available :1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Table B : ID    1 2 3 4 5 6

```
Available 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Table C  :  ID  1 2 3 4 5 6

```
Available 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

Table D  : ID   1 2 3 4 5 6

```
Available 1 1 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: What is the result set you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `intersect` if you want all the `available` values to be `0`:

```
select id from a where available = 0
intersect
select id from b where available = 0
intersect
select id from c where available = 0
intersect
select id from d where available = 0;
```

If you want *any* of them to be 0, then use `union` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to use it in Java , but it keeps giving me sql syntax error